# Not able to check mutual ssl enabled API output on WSO2 Dev Portal-3.1.0

Tags: postman, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have enabled Mutual SSL for API in WSO2 publisher by creating and adding own certificate and published the API, but after subscribing API in DevPortal, I was unable to get Output, getting error like "wrong credentials".
I have also tried in Postman with SSL certificates enabled, I was getting **Error: Unable to verify the first certificate**.

For certificate creation I have used this command:

```
 openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privatekey.key -out certificate.crt
```

I have tested it in CURL, I was getting output with this command:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>" -v '<API URL>' --cert <.crt file> --key <.key file>
```

But I am unable to get output on Devportal, Is there a way to add certificate in devportal for calling API, Need Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking a mutual SSL API from the Devportal cannot be done. You can use either Postman or curl.

Did you try disabling SSL certificate verification in Postman settings? Please try to follow the instructions given in documentation [1].

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-mutual-ssl/#create-an-api-secured-with-mutual-ssl

Comment: Thanks @TharikaMadrapperuma, I was getting output while disabling SSL Certificate on Postman but with a warning sign **"first certificate verification failed"**.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an issue with the certificates when trying to request an untrusted host. I think you are using "localhost". https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6354